# Expo can't install Expo Go on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, expo, expo-go

I have just installed an Android Emulator - which is `Pixel 4 API 28` - on my Windows 11 computer. I have a project in Expo and I want to test it on Android Emulator. For this, the Expo needs to install Expo Go on Emulator to load my project. By default, it installs automatically when I request for installation by pressing `a` on my terminal. It detects the connected and available devices on my computer and installs the application.

But for me this does not happen. Instead of installing automatically, the terminal prints me this:

```
› Opening on Android...

. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/authorize-android-device_4_API_28
```

This link leads to a 404 page of Github but if I remove the "_4_API_28" part from hyperlink it leads to "Authorize Android Device" page from `fyi`. This page guides how to reset USB debug permissions of my device to allow my computer to get debug access. I have already did that on my android emulator but nothing changed, it still prints that message.

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue and install Expo Go on my android emulator property?

Comment: I believe it should lead to this link: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/authorize-android-device.md

For some reason they changed the name there, but haven't on emulator.